# Batch File execution on remote windows server via batch file on another windows server

Tags: windows, batch-file, ssh, cmd

I am trying to call a batch file placed on a remote windows server from my windows server. I have freeSSHd installed on the remote server. I tried using putty/plink but of no result.

Syntax of command I am using is:

**Putty:** `start E:\putty.exe -ssh user12@serverIP -pw "abcd12" call sample.bat`

**Plink:** `start E:\plink.exe -ssh user12@serverIP -pw "abcd12" cmd.exe -m E://sample.txt`

I even tried all variants of above two commands like "-m file.txt" etc. Also I am able to execute batch file via login into putty console but not via calling batch file placed on my windows server.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to include what partial solutions you found and how they didn't work. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Answer (score 5):

This is how to start remote programs in Windows.

```
wmic /node:servername process call create "cmd.exe c:\\somefolder\\batch.bat"
```

Files executed this way are invisible on the remote computer.

For Help

```
wmic /?
wmic process /?
wmic process get /?
wmic process set /?
wmic process call /?
wmic process call create /?
wmic process /node /?
wmic process /user /?
wmic process /password /?
```

Comment: If you type that in windows it will run a batch on another computer.

Comment: Hi Still I couldn't understand you. How these command help me in executing batch script on remote windows server. Can u pls give me an example.

Comment: I did give you an example. How to run `c:\somefolder\batch.bat` on a remote computer called `servername`. If you want to run it on your machine then just `\\servername\C$\somefolder\batch.bat` eg: `C:\Users\user>\\serenity\c$\autoexec.bat`

C:\Users\user>REM Dummy file for NTVDM

Comment: Windows is easy to use. Stop complicating it.

Comment: Ya I agree with your point, but the server on which I need to execute my batch script is not directly mapped to my window server. If I run the command \\serverIP\C:\somefolder\batch.bat then it gives me the error "the network path not found"

Comment: It's not a drive letter but the Default Administrative Share (C$, D$ if you have a d drive, ADMIN$ (C:\windows). The UNC syntax is `\\Server\Share\path\file` so `\\127.0.0.1\C$\Windows\explorer.exe`. You have to be an admin to use these shares. `$` means hidden share. The shares are created at boot. You can use `RunAs` if you need to be a different user. `Runas /?`.